# Xamarin.Forms UWP project throws exception when compiled with .Net Native

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have UWP Xamarin.Forms project, I enabled "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" option in my UWP Project, but when running the App it is throwing below error:

> System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException:
>   ''Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsPlatformServices' is missing
>   metadata. For more information, please visit
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=392859'

Also I have added below lines in my default.rd.xml file:

```xml
<Type Name="System.EventHandler" Dynamic="Required All" /> 
 <Namespace Name="System.Reflection" Serialize="Required All" />
 <Namespace Name="System.Private.Reflection.Core" Serialize="Required All" />
```

Comment: Have you tried to use this [solution](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Target_Invocation_Exception_when_using_Compile_with_.NET_Native_tool_chain)?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes I tried that but it didn't worked, I added below line in my default.rd.xml and finally it did worked:
  <Type Name="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsPlatformServices" Serialize="Required All" />

Comment: Good, May I convert your comment to the answer for this issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by  adding below lines in the `default.rd.xml` file.

```
<Type Name="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsPlatformServices" Serialize="Required All" />
```